# How to add scrollbar only to tbody and not fixed thead

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to create a table that has a scrollable `<tbody>` with a fixed `<thead>`. I have achieved that here https://jsfiddle.net/ghnfzwm6/16/.

However, this is not quite what I would like. I want the scroll bar to start where the `<tbody>` starts. I have attempted to do so by adding

```
height: 546px;
max-height: 546px;
overflow-y: scroll; /* only Y axis scroll */
```

to `<tbody>` and removing it from `#tasks-table-wrapper`. I also made `<tbody>` and `<tr>` `display: block;`

Here is the result https://jsfiddle.net/4gLwp697/3/. The problem now is that `<thead>` does not line up with `<tbody>`. I can fix that by specifying column widths, but I want them to be auto.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
#tasks tr {
  display: block;
}
```

with

```
#tasks tr {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5nt18cL0/

Comment: @JackP True, I was wrong because the example data was all 3 characters.

Comment: @JackP Seemingly by adding `table-layout: fixed;`, it works ?

Comment: Nothing has changed? Still mis-aligned http://prntscr.com/qobj9c

Comment: Oh I see, you fixed it moving over when there's more content. Great but it's still not lined up properly.

Comment: @JackP How about adding `width: calc(100% + scrollbarwidth)` for `tbody`? https://jsfiddle.net/5n07awcs/ *(or `#tasks tbody tr` instead if you want to keep the scrollbar visible)*

Answer (score 0):

consider this code snippet, There is no direct solution to your problem, This is determined by the 'table' feature. The solutions for the current mainstream frameworks are as follows, You need to set the width of 'columns'.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#content {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

#tasks-table-wrapper {
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
}
.scrollbar-wrap {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100px;
}
.black-table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  font-size: 0;
  background-color: #121212;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.black-table td {
  color: #bbb;
  font-size: 11px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  padding: 15px 30px;
}
.black-table th {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1c1c1c;
  position: sticky; /* keep TH on top */
  top: 0;
  background-color: #121212;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div id="tasks-table-wrapper">
    <table class="black-table">
        <colgroup>
          <col width="180">
          <col width="180">
          <col width="180">
          <col width="180">
        </colgroup>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Column 1</th>
          <th>Column 2</th>
          <th>Column 3</th>
          <th>Column 4</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
    <div class="scrollbar-wrap">
      <table class="black-table">
        <colgroup>
          <col width="180">
          <col width="180">
          <col width="180">
          <col width="163">
        </colgroup>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>AAA</td>
            <td>BBB</td>
            <td>CCC</td>
            <td>DDD</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>AAA</td>
            <td>BBB</td>
            <td>CCC</td>
            <td>DDD</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>AAA</td>
            <td>BBB</td>
            <td>CCC</td>
            <td>DDD</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>AAA</td>
            <td>BBB</td>
            <td>CCC</td>
            <td>DDD</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can see [VUE Table with fixed header](https://element.eleme.cn/#/en-US/component/table), Review the table elements.

Comment: The content in the table is going to change so this does not solve anything for me unfortunately.

Comment: @Jack P The 'JavaScript' solution is to split your 'table' into two separate pieces, I have tried the questions you asked before, and I have looked up a lot of information. The above scheme is the one most frameworks use.

Comment: The JavaScript solution would be to calculate the width of each `<th>` and each column and take whichever is the largest and set the column width to be that.

Comment: @Jack P You can think, However, using this method requires you to consider the width of the scroll bar, As far as I am concerned, this plan is troublesome. But there is no better solution.